# Bounding KL divergence using element wise difference in probability

Tags: real-analysis, probability

Let $S = \{1,2,\ldots, N\}$. Let $|Q(j) - P(j)| <\epsilon$, for all $j \in S$.
Now, $$KL(P || Q) = \sum_{j}P(j) \log \cfrac{P(j)}{Q(j)}$$
Using the inequality $\log \, x \leq 1-x$ and the fact that $P(j) \leq 1$, we have
$$KL(P || Q) \leq \sum_{j} \left[\cfrac{Q(j)-P(j)}{Q(j)} \right]$$
Now the numerator can be bounded but how can we bound the denominator?

Comment: Does $Q$ have full support? If not, I think there are counterexamples where the KL divergence can be unbounded.

Comment: $Q$ is zero only when $P$ is zero.

Comment: Even if it does not have full support, you can set P(1) = epsilon, and $Q_n(1) = 1/e^{n!}$. where $n$ is just some indexing over some distributions. Now, you can see that you can make the bound arbitrarily bad while satisfying the given difference constraint. As soon as you make sure $Q_n$ is far from 0, you can use your bound to give such an upper bound.